# Django How to add to a foreign key field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to design a model for the currrent user to see all the people he referred. I create another model to keep track of all the referral relation between users, such as 'stephen -> jack', 'stephen -> mike'

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    // .......  a lot more fields
    referred_who = models.ForeignKey('referral', blank=True, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Referral(models.Model):
    referrer = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    referred = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE,  related_name='referred')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("referrer", "referred"),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.referrer.username + ' -> ' + self.referred.username
```

The question I am having right now is that one user can refer multiple users, but the field 'referred_who' I use to keep track of all the referral relations can only keep one of them. In my back-end admin it shows:

```
Referred who: stephen1 -> stephen2 (with a dropdown with all the relations but I can only choose one of them)
```

What I want is somethig like:

```
Referred who: stephen1 -> stephen2  stephen1 -> stephen3  stephen1 -> stephen4
```

And I can access this 'Referred_who' field to get all the relations this current user has.

Is there a way to add to the foreign key field instead of just choosing one of them? Can someone show me an example to do it? Many thanks.

Comment: You are doing it in the wrong direction and you don't need the `Referral` class. Just add a `referred_by = models.ForeignKey('self', ...)` field to your `CustomUser`. If you want to store extra information (such as `referral_date`) you can use a `ManyToMany` relation with a through table. See Django documentation for details.

Comment: Hi, could you explain how does adding referred_by = models.ForeignKey('self', ...) helps me to get all the users referred by the current user? I still need a field for the user to track who he has referred, right? Because I want to access "user.referral_who" to get all the users.

Comment: This is a very broad topic but to put it simply `ForeignKey` fields both ways. Please refer to Django docs and read more about relational databases.

Comment: The best way to do it is self referential model also mentioned by Selcuk, check docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `Referral` class. Your `referred_who` field can "point" to the `CustomUser`. I renamed it to `referred_by` and added `related_name='referees'`. This would mean that if user `A` referred user `B` and user `B` referred user `C` and `D`, then `B.referred_by == A` and `B.referees == (C, D)`:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='referees')
```

Then, you could create a custom form to display in the admin, something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.db import models

class CustomUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'

    referees = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['referees'].initial = self.instance.referees.all()

class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomUserForm

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

NOTE: This won't save the chosen users in the `referees` field yet, you would need to do that by overriding the `save` method in the form but I do hope this gets you started.